# Force language on first page call Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, localization

I use Laravel 5.4 and my application works fine. 
My routes and views are display correctly like:

```
app.de/de  
app.de/en  
app.de/de/kontakt 
app.de/en/contact
```

On my first page call I want to force the default lang like a redirect from app.de to -> app.de/de

web.php:

```
Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
App::setLocale($locale);

return view('welcome');});
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a redirect from the home page to the "de" home page https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirects

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. This solution works:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/de');
});

Route::get('/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('{locale}/contact', 'ContactController@index');
```